# When is the fundamental group of a fibration a semi-direct product?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

Let $f:S\to B$ be a fibration from a projective complex surface onto a curve $B$. 
Assume that $f$ has no multiple fibres. Then there is an exact sequence 
$$\pi_1(F)\to \pi_1 (S)\to \pi_1 (B) \to 1 ,$$ where $F$ is a generic fiber.

If $f$ has a section $B\to S$, then one has a section $\pi_1 (B) \to \pi_1 (S)$, and therefore $\pi_1 (S)$ is the semi-direct product of the image $V_f$ of $\pi_1(F)\to \pi_1 (S)$ by the group $\pi_1 (B)$.

Is there a reciprocal : if $\pi_1 (S)$ is the semi-direct product of the groups $V_f$ by $\pi_1 (B)$, is it true that one has a section $B \to S$ of $f$ ?

Comment: What if $B=\mathbb{P}^1$? $\pi _1(S)$ is trivially equal to $V_f$, but it easy to give examples where $f$ has no section.

Comment: Also, since you said "generic fiber", I'm guessing this is a fibration in the sense algebraic geometry, and not topology? I think you need to remove the points in the base with special fibers to make this true.

Comment: But I think what is true is that if $B$ and $F$ are curves of positive genus (thus aspherical) in a topological fibration, then if the exact sequence splits, there's a section up to homotopy. I'd have to think if there's actually an honest section of topological spaces, let alone an algebraic one.

Comment: In your question by "section" you mean a holomorphic section, or topological section?

Comment: @aglearner I am thinking about holomorphic sections.

Comment: @abx Yes, good point ! and what about higher genus curves ?

Comment: @KevinCasto I do not know what is a section up to homotopy, can you explain ? Also what is aspherical, and how it changes things compared to genus 0 and 1 ?

Comment: @XavierRoulleau Aspherical = $K(\pi,1)$; I include genus 1 for "positive". Read 1.B of Hatcher for more info. If the group sequence splits, there will be a (unique up to homotopy) map $B \to S$ inducing the splitting, but it could fail to be a section on the nose: all you have is that the composition $B \to B$ is homotopic, not equal, to the identity. But again, there might be a way to fix this, topologically at least.

Comment: @XavierRoulleau Oh duh sorry, of course you can fix this topologically: just apply the homotopy lifting property to the homotopy from $\pi \circ s$ to $\text{id}_B$. But again, no idea how to extend to the holomorphic category. Also arguably more important is my first comment: you need to remove points in the base to make this a topological fibration!